# Css Menu Aligment

Tags: css, css-float

Hi i have a simple question, what am i doing that is doubling the height of the menu bar and applying it to the area bellow it?

Simple enough thanks again

http://www.mcdanielstudio.com/

```
#nav {
width: 100%;
float: left;
margin: 0 0 3em 0;
padding: 0;
list-style: none;
background-color: #f2f2f2;
border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc; 
border-top: 1px solid #ccc; }
#nav li {
float: left; }
#nav li a {
display: block;
padding: 8px 15px;
text-decoration: none;
font-weight: bold;
color: #069;
border-right: 1px solid #ccc; }
#nav li a:hover {
color: #c00;
background-color: #fff; }


#main_content {
clear: both;
margin-top: 0px;

border-left-color: #000000;
border-left-style: dashed;
border-left-width: 2px;
margin: 0px;
border-bottom: 0px;
border-right: 0px;
border-top: 0px;
border-left: 0px;
float: left;
font-size: 12px;
color: #000000;
text-align: left;
background-color: #FFFFFF;
padding-bottom: 3em;
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Remove `margin-bottom:3em` from your `#nav`

Answer (score 0):

You have a 3em bottom margin on `#nav`.